# How to deal with SQL database in GitHub

Tags: python, postgresql, github

I'm doing a web scraping + data analysis project that consists of scraping product prices every day, clean the data, and store that data into a PostgreSQL database. The final user won't have access to the data in this database (scraping every day becomes huge, so eventually I won't be able to upload in GitHub), but I want to explain how to replicate the project. The steps are basically:

- Scraping with Selenium (Python), and save the raw data into CSV files (already in GitHub);
- Read these CSV files, clean the data, and store it into the database (the cleaning script already in GitHub);
- Retrieve the data from the database to create dashboards and anything that I want (not yet implemented).

To clarify, my question is about how can I teach someone that sees my project, to replicate it, given that this person won't have the database info (tables, columns). My idea is:

1. Add SQL queries in a folder, showing how to create the database skeleton (same tables and columns);
2. Add in README info like creating the environment variables to access the database;

It is okay doing that? I'm looking for best practices in this context. Thanks!

Comment: you can add an sql dump of only the tables structure (NO DATA) and user can import this dump into her own server to replicate the DB structure

Comment: okay, I did that now. But looking into the .sql file, it reveals my username. Not a big deal for this project specifically, but this wouldn't be a problem in a "real" application?